# How do I install wkhtmltopdf with the PHP bindings on Linux (centos)

Tags: php, linux, wkhtmltopdf

How do I install wkhtmltopdf with the PHP bindings on Linux (centos 5+)?

My question is slightly different to the other questions because I need help setting up the php bindings as well.

Thanks

Jason

Comment: Not a programming question. belongs on serverfault.

Comment: oh yeh, how does one migrate it

Comment: `wkhtmltopdf` is a single binary and really not difficult to invoke. Which bindings please and why would you want it? If you are referring to http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp than that's a single php script too, easy to upload, hardly an issue.

Comment: i was talking about this one: https://github.com/mreiferson/php-wkhtmltox but your link looks nice and easy. will use that instead. Thanks @mario. post an answer to this question with that and i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler method to programmatically invoke wkhtmltopdf:
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp

PHP bindings are really overkill for this applicaiton. In the majority of cases you can get away with just executing it:

```
exec("wkhtmltopdf http://example.org/ pdf1.pdf");
$pdf = file_get_contents("pdf1.pdf");
```