# adding js script to wkhtmltopdf in exec()

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

How to use wkhtmltopdf page option: --run-script inside of exec()

```
exec(path/to/wkhtmltopdf --run-script(???)  path/to/pdf-ed/doc  path-to-output-pdf))
```

Comment: I wrote this in a recent post here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25780131/executing-wkhtmltopdf-via-php-throws-error

Comment: wkhtmltopdf works ok - no problem here, just that particular option: --run-script eludes me

Comment: Is this PHP? That does not look like a valid exec command, how does yours actually look like?

Answer (score 0):

The `--run-script` argument takes JavaScript passed at the command line. NOT a script file, but actual script content.

```
$jsCode  = '/* JavaScript code that manipulates the DOM... */';
$webURL  = 'http://example.com';
$pdfFile = '/tmp/output.pdf';
exec('wkhtmltopdf '.
     '--run-script '.escapeshellarg($jsCode).' '.
     escapeshellarg($webURL).' '.
     escapeshellarg($pdfFile));
```