# html2pdf - Too many tag closures found for [table]

Tags: php, html, mysql, html2pdf

we are creating a PDF in php using html2pdf. This also works quite well.

However, we fetch data from the DB into an html table. If it becomes too much data, we need a second page. But this is not generated because we get this error here:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\HtmlParsingException: Too many tag closures found for [table].
```

Our Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>toolName</th>
        <th>toolCode</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($tools as $i => $tool): ?>
        <tr style="font-size: 20px;">
            <td><img src="<?= $settings_BaseURL ?>/assets/images/anderes/checkbox.png" alt="" 
            style="width: 27px; height: 30px;"><?= $tool['toolName'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $tool['toolBarCode'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to using something else to generate the PDF? You can use wkhtmltopdf which is a command line utility and directly pass your html to it or you can use headless Chrome with Puppeteer.

Wkhtmltopdf - [How do I get WKHTMLTOPDF to execute via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663814/how-do-i-get-wkhtmltopdf-to-execute-via-php)

Headless Chrome with Puppeteer - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer

In case you don't want to set up headless chrome and puppeteer yourself, you can use an API like PDFMark - https://pdfmark.com  (Disclaimer: I am the developer)

Answer (score -2):

Use `<?php echo` tag instead of `<?=`

Comment: `<?=` is shorthand for `<?php echo`, no need to change it